# quantity option in products list page in OpenCart 1.5

Tags: php, opencart

I need to enable user to set quantity of products and add it to shopping cart in **list of products page**. there is only (**add to cart**) options without quantity field.

How can I fix this problem ?!!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a "problem" that needs "fixing". You are after extended functionality. I'm guessing you want something like this

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=3487